# How does `mypy` know the signature of the pydantic model?

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

How does `mypy` know the signature of the `pydantic` model in this manner?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int

Model(a='asd')  # error: Argument "a" to "Model" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

How can `pydantic` `BaseModel`'s metaclass change the `__init__` signature?

Comment: Thanks to [their plugin](https://docs.pydantic.dev/mypy_plugin/), are you interested in internal details of plugin implementation? It is released to the public, you can just examine its source code.

Comment: It's working without the plugin

Comment: Wow, nice catch! It was the plugin reliability zone before, but PEP681 changed the things. See my answer for current explanation. (btw, the documentation page I linked is outdated too and mentions explicitly that plugin is necessary to generate `__init__` for type chechers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pydantic uses [PEP681](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/) `dataclass_transform` on model metaclass to achieve behaviour similar to native `dataclasses.dataclass` decorator in order to generate an `__init__` method for type checkers. Reading [the source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/main.py#L60):

```py
@typing_extensions.dataclass_transform(kw_only_default=True, field_specifiers=(Field,))
class ModelMetaclass(ABCMeta):
    ...  # [omitted by me]

class BaseModel(_repr.Representation, metaclass=ModelMetaclass):
    ... # [omitted by me]
```

In PEP:

> If `dataclass_transform` is applied to a class, dataclass-like semantics will be assumed for any class that directly or indirectly derives from the decorated class or uses the decorated class as a metaclass.

PEP example (very similar to what pydantic does):

```py
# The ``ModelMeta`` metaclass and ``ModelBase`` class are defined by
# a library. This could be in a type stub or inline.
@typing.dataclass_transform()
class ModelMeta(type): ...

class ModelBase(metaclass=ModelMeta): ...

# The ``ModelBase`` class can now be used to create new model
# subclasses, like this:
class CustomerModel(ModelBase):
    id: int
    name: str
```